# What changes are required in Excel 2019 for Windows 11?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, windows-11

I haven't heard of any, but the question will arise... Do we need to change our VBA Macro Code to accommodate Windows 11? It's a similar question to the 32-bit/64-bit issue, where conditional code was required for calls to standard functions. And our clients want reassurance that a similar type of issue won't happen if they update to Windows 11.

Comment: I believe that they are wrong, but I got closed on StackOverflow as they deemed this a HARDWARE question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

No reassurance is possible without actually trying it out.
It should be quite easy, as Windows 11 is
[available for download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download).
You could install it in a virtual machine while waiting for the official
upgrade.

However, Windows 11 is only some cosmetics as regarding the user interface
and some new features, mostly about security. It doesn't change anything
profound in the underlying system.
It's a pretty small upgrade that could have been called a Windows 10
upgrade, but wasn't for marketing reasons.

Note that it's not sure that all your clients' computers would be capable
of doing this upgrade, but it will be OK to stay in Windows 10, as
it will be fully compatible with Windows 11.